# 2014 Community Moderator Election

Tags: discussion, moderators, election

The 2014 Community Moderator Election is now underway!

Community moderator elections have three phases:

1. Nomination phase
2. Primary phase
3. Election phase

Most elections take between two and three weeks, but this depends on how many candidates there are.

Please visit the official election page at

https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/election

for more detail, and to participate!

If you have general questions about the election process, or questions for moderator candidates, feel free to ask them here on meta -- just make sure your questions are tagged [election](/questions/tagged/election).

Comment: Where/how do we nominate people? I'm a bit unclear.

Answer (score 5):

I will not be seeking a nomination, I have been a moderator for approximately 3 years here, and while I am ecstatic that the community has been growing, and helped out where I could, I am not going to seek to become a moderator here now that the site has graduated. I wish to all of the candidates the best of luck, and I'll continue to assist where I can with this site. Thanks for allowing me to be a moderator for this time!

Comment: On behalf of SE Inc, I thank you for your years of hard work as a mod here!

Comment: Thanks for everything!